# Projective coordinates for Montgomery curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have this Montgomery curve $y^2=x^3+10x^2+x \mod 83$ and a point $Q(3,28)$,
doubling this point in affine coordinates I get $2Q(61,35)$.

Switching to projective coordinates I know that $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$ and $Z = 1$ at the beginning so $Q(3,28,1)$, following [the Wikipedia formulas for doubling in projective coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve), I get $X_2p = 64$ and $Z_2p = 65$.

How do I verify that this point in projective coordinates belongs to the curve? Do I need the $y$-coordinate in projective coordinates? If so, how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I verify that this point in projective coordinates belongs to the curve?

Assuming that you don't have the $y$ coordinate, then the requirement on $x$ is that $x^3 + 10x^2 + x$ is a quadratic residue; that is, there exists a $y$ such that $y^2$ is that value.

Now, you have the projective coordinates; the corresponding requirement is that:

$$(Y/Z)^2 = (X/Z)^3 + 10(X/Z)^2 + (X/Z)$$

Multiplying both sides by $Z^4$, we get

$$(YZ)^2 = X^3Z + 10X^2Z^2 + XZ^3$$

The lhs is a square (and by selecting the correct $Y$, can be any square, assuming $Z \ne 0$), and so the condition is that $X^3Z + 10X^2Z^2 + XZ^3$ is a quadratic residue.

I believe that testing this value for quadratic residuosity will be cheaper than recovering the possible $y$ values.

Comment: You wrote: *The lhs is a square (and by selecting the correct Y,can be any square, assuming Z≠0), and so the condition is that $X^3Z+10X^2Z^2+XZ^3$ is a quadratic residue*. What would be the formula for calculating $Y$ if I wanted to convert the point $Q2$ from projective coordinates to affine coordinates? For the $x$-coordinate there is no problem, I know that $x$ = $X*Z^-1$ and I get exactly $61$, but how would I get $y$ = $35$?

Comment: @filippopolidori: the most straight-forward way to compute $Z^{-1} = 23$ and $x = XZ^{-1} = 61$ (which you have done), and then compute $y^2 = x^3 + 10x^2 + x = 63$, and then squareroot $y^2$; because $83 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, the straight-forward $(y^2)^{(p+1)/4} = 48$ works; remember, $-48 = 35$ is also a valid y-coordinate (because it is also a square root of $y^2$)